# Elasticsearch aggregate by nested object property

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index where i store all the survey responses as a json object.

Example:

```
{
"@timestamp": "2019-04-29T07:46:34.184Z",
"id": 54448437,
"questionResponses": [
  {
    "questionId": 1000000000,
    "insights": [
      {
        "categoryId": 50071,
        "feature": "experience",
        "tonality": "positive",
        "score": 1,
        "id": 253042338,
        "opinion": "great"
      },
      {
        "categoryId": 50071,
        "feature": "Overall Experience",
        "tonality": "negative",
        "score": -1,
        "id": 253042357,
        "opinion": "very misleading"
      },
      {
        "categoryId": 50015,
        "feature": "video",
        "tonality": "negative",
        "score": -1,
        "id": 253042358,
        "opinion": "misleading"
      },
      {
        "categoryId": 50009,
        "feature": "classes",
        "tonality": "neutral",
        "score": -1,
        "id": 253042364,
        "opinion": "didn't even get to attend."
      }
    ],
    "response": "While I had a great experience with both my girls, promising a NICU and having one available and open are two different things and very misleading. This whole video feels misleading to me. My birth plan was between me and my doctor both times and the hospital was just my location. They do offer classes but they fill super fast and we're very limited that I didn't even get to attend. I loved the attention and care that I received while there ...",
    "id": 425994747
  }
],
"source_name": "Survey 1"
}
```

Now, I have a requirement were I need to get the document counts based on the sum of insights score per category id.

I need to get the positive document and negative document count.

The output should look like

```
{"categoryId": 50071,
"positiveDocumentCount": 0,
"neutralDocumentCount": 1,
"negativeDocumentCount": 0}

{"categoryId": 50015,
"positiveDocumentCount": 0,
"neutralDocumentCount": 0,
"negativeDocumentCount": 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure questionResponses and questionResponses.insights are nested

Try this -

```
{  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "questionResponses":{  
         "nested":{  
            "path":"questionResponses"
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "insights":{  
               "nested":{  
                  "path":"questionResponses.insights"
               },
               "aggs":{  
                  "cats":{  
                     "terms":{  
                        "field":"questionResponses.insights.categoryId"
                     },
                     "aggs":{  
                        "positiveDocumentCount":{  
                           "filter":{  
                              "term":{  
                                 "questionResponses.insights.tonality.keyword":"positive"
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        "neutralDocumentCount":{  
                           "filter":{  
                              "term":{  
                                 "questionResponses.insights.tonality.keyword":"neutral"
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        "negativeDocumentCount":{  
                           "filter":{  
                              "term":{  
                                 "questionResponses.insights.tonality.keyword":"negative"
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```